# Android Market listings, "What's New" appearing above "Description"

Tags: android, google-play

Does anyone know how to change the order of these? I'd like the "Description" to appear before the "What's New" section.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"What's New" appears above "Description" if the app is installed. If the app is not installed then "What's New" is not displayed.

There is no way to change this. In fact it makes perfect sense as a user performing a new installation would not really care about what is new but a user upgrading would.

Comment: lol, now I feel silly.  Thanks for the quick reply Kuffs this was driving me nuts! :-)  I can't award the bounty until tomorrow but will do so then.  Cheers!